# How to preprocess makefiles

Tags: makefile

How to show the makefile after it's been preprocessed? For example, if we have two makefiles:

```
# Makefile
include Makefile2

# Makefile2
a:a.c
    gcc -o a a.c
```

Then `<preprocessor> Makefile` should give:

```
a:a.c
    gcc -o a a.c
```

It's similar to what a C preprocessor does (`gcc -E`). Is there such a makefile preprocessor?

Comment: The closest you can get is the output of `make -p`.  However, that both does more processing than just including makefiles (it also expands variable references that appear in immediate contexts, such as target and prerequisite lists), and it's also not guaranteed to always emit a valid makefile (although that would be nice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify for which make tool you are writing makefile. Assuming that it is GNU make, you can try running makefile with **-n (--just-print)** option [See Command-Line Options chapter here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/ch12.pdf). That will show what make is going to execute without execution (however, the commands needed for evaluation of variables will be executed). This is probably the closest to what you want to see.

> This causes make to read the makefile and print every command it would
>   normally execute to update the target but without executing them.

Apart from that there is **$(warning )** function to debug makefiles. You can place it almost to any part in makefile and the following will show you the values of all defined variables in that place:

```
$(warning Variables HERE: .VARIABLES)
```

Comment: This option just shows the command. It doesn't show the complete makefile. For example, makefile variables can be modified in many places in the makefile and it's helpful to see how they're updated.

Comment: @Cyker then, you can try another option --debug=verbose. I understand that it's not exactly what you want, but I doubt there is a simple  option to do that.